# ConcurrentModificationException - checkForComodification(ArrayList.java)

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

For the Below java program with Hash Map, ConcurrentModification Exception thrown, i had marked the lines where the Exception is thrown in the Program.

I had skipped the login of Insertion of Data into the HashMap for now

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;

 public class MainClass {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>> arrMain = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>();

         HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hm = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

         ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

         // Code to build the above Maps with all required Data, Skipped for Now

         //******************Scenario 1****************
         for (HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> dataMap : arrMain) { //ConcurrentModification Exception
             for (String s : dataMap.get("Key")) {
                 ArrayList<String> newStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
                 newStrings.addAll(dataMap.get("Key")); 
                 newStrings.add("New String");
                 dataMap.put("Key", newStrings);
             }

         }

         //******************Scenario 2****************
         for (HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> dataMap : arrMain) {//ConcurrentModification Exception
             for (String s : dataMap.get("Key")) {
                 dataMap.get("Key").add("New String"); 
             }

         }

     }

 }
```

Error :

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:819)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:791)
```

Comment: you can not iterate over hashmap and use addall or add at the same time. it is like to read and change a location at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

When ever you try to modify the Collection while iterate you will get `ConcurrentModificationException`. You can try with `Iterator` to avoid this.

Eg: `Iterator` with `Map`

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("a", "a1");
    map.put("b", "b1");
    map.put("c", "c1");
    System.out.println(map);
    Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
        it.remove(); // no a ConcurrentModificationException
    }
    System.out.println(map);
```

Out put:

```
{b=b1, c=c1, a=a1}
b = b1
c = c1
a = a1
{}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have marked 2 `ConcurrentModificationException` points in your code but only one is reproducible and reasonable.

The 2nd one:

```
for (HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> dataMap : arrMain) {
     for (String s : dataMap.get("Key")) { // HERE 
         dataMap.get("Key").add("New String"); 
     }
}
```

`dataMap.get("Key")` returns an `ArrayList` to which inside the `for` loop you add another element:

```
dataMap.get("Key").add("New String");
```

And right after adding an element (modifying it) the `for` loop would continue. You add an element to the list right in the middle of iterating over it. This causes the `ConcurrentModificationException` (under the hood the enhanced `for` uses the iterator of the list to go over its elements, and the iterators `next()` method throws this exception if the list is modified since the creation of the iterator).

The 1st point in your code where you indicated `ConcurrentModificationException`, it causes no exception because you iterate over a list and you modify another list, a new list which you create inside the `for` loop. But I doubt this is what you really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

> A hash table supporting full concurrency of retrievals and adjustable expected concurrency for updates.
>
> This class obeys the same functional specification as Hashtable, and includes versions of methods corresponding to each method of Hashtable.
>
> However, even though all operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do not entail locking, and there is not any support for locking the entire table in a way that prevents all access.
>
> This class is fully interoperable with Hashtable in programs that rely on its thread safety but not on its synchronization details.

---

You can use iterator. **iterators are designed to be used by only one thread at a time. They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException.**

[ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

```
public class ConcurrentModificationException
             extends RuntimeException
```

> This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.
>
> For example, it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a Collection while another thread is iterating over it.

### See also

- [Concurrent Hash Map article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp08223/index.html)